# new dataframe based on conditions of 2 other dataframses

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with time series data (dates in the columns, data in the rows) and need to create a new dataframe based on conditions met for each individual dataframe.

So. e.g.

if field in df A >10 and respective field in df B > 3 write in the respective field in df C "True".

```
DF A
Name 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003
A     2     11   7   12    50
B     4     5   5    5       15
C      19    40   6    90     50


DF B
Name 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003
A     32     4   1   1    45
B     4     5   5    5      4
C      1    5   1    0     5


DF C
Name 1999     2000   2001    2002    2003
A     False   True   False   False    True
B     False   False   False   False   True
C       False   True   False   False    True
```

Is there any solution that does not requiring to loop through each field?

In Column A I have names and in row 1 the dates.

I tried with:

```
df_d = np.where((df_a > 10) & (df_b > 3))
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example with some data and an explanation of the desire output. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works exactlly how you wrote it in you question.

```
df_c = (df_a>10) & (df_b>3)
```

**Your example**

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame({1999: [2,4,19], 2000: [11, 5, 40], 2001: [7,5,6], 2002:[12,5,90], 2003:[50,15, 50]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame({1999: [32,4,1], 2000: [4, 5, 5], 2001: [1,5,1], 2002:[1,5,0], 2003:[45,4, 5]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df_c = (df_a>10) & (df_b>3)
>>>df_c
    1999   2000   2001   2002  2003
A  False   True  False  False  True
B  False  False  False  False  True
C  False   True  False  False  True
```